# How to use in views a controller helper method from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I have two controllers having a helper method that has same name but returns different things:

```
class My1Controller < ApplicationController
  helper_method :my_helper

  def show
    ...
  end


  private

  def my_helper
    "Something from My1 controller"
  end
end

class My2Controller < ApplicationController
  helper_method :my_helper

  def show
    ...
  end


  private

  def my_helper
    "Something from My2 controller"
  end
end
```

In the `app/views/my1/show.html.erb` view related to `My1Controller` I would like to use the returned value of `my_helper` from `My2Controller`.

How can I make that?

Comment: You mean you are using `app/views/my1/show.html.erb` for My2Controller?

Comment: @ray I am using / would like to use just a helper method from My2Controller in `app/views/my1/show.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `my_helper` into a separated helper.
and include that helper back to controller where you want to use `my_helper`

```
# app/helpers/params_helper.rb

module ParamsHelper
  def sort_params
    params.permit(:sort).fetch(:sort, nil)
  end
  [...]
end
```

Comment: Could you be more clear (e.g. including the helper back to controller, calling `my_helper` from another controller)? A more specific example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to put the helper method in the helper module and use that in the controller with `view_context` as follows:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def fancy_helper(str)
    str.titleize
  end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @title = view_context.fancy_helper "dogs are awesome"
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer to the question's issue.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use Ruby metaprogramming:

```
# app/views/my1/show.html.erb
<%= My2Controller.new.send(:my_helper) %>
```

But is this a good practice or there is something better?

Answer (score 0):

Add following in `My1Controller` & `My2Controller`,

```
  include HelperMethods
  helper_method :my_helper1
```

And add method in module defined,

```
module HelperMethods
  private

  def my_helper
    "Something from My2 controller"
  end
end
```

Helper method name should be uniq which are used same controller so update name